# How to speed up code in ParallelDo loops?

Tags: parallelization

I have a piece of code that I'm trying to run in a `ParallelDo` over 32 kernels. Using a normal `Do` loop in a kernel *Mathematica* takes about 6 minutes to do the calculation, however, in the `ParallelDo` loop across 32 kernels it takes just over a minute. Surely it should be much quicker than this (about 11 seconds)?! Here is the code:

```
LaunchKernels[2*$ProcessorCount - $KernelCount];
dk = 1;

ParallelEvaluate[
  g = 2*10^-1;
  ϕ = 1;
  m = 1;
  f = 7;
  lattsize = 50;
  p[P_, α_, β_] := {P*Sin[α]*Cos[β], P*Sin[α]*Sin[β], P*Cos[α]};
  q[Q_, a_] := {Q*Sin[a], 0, Q*Cos[a]};
  k[X_] := {0, 0, X};
  X = Interpolation[Table[{i, i}, {i, 0, lattsize, 10^-3}]];
  ω[x_] := Sqrt[x.x + m^2];
  (*x:=p,y:=q,z:=k,s:=k+(-)p+(-)q*)
  A1[x_, y_, z_, s_] := (1 + (g*ϕ^2)/(8*ω[x]^2))*ω[x] + 
      (1 + (g*ϕ^2)/(8*ω[y]^2))*ω[y] + (1 + (g*ϕ^2)/(8*ω[z]^2))*ω[z] + 
         (1 + (g*ϕ^2)/(8*ω[s]^2))*ω[s];

   minA1={};

   maxA1={};

 ];

ParallelDo[
 solA1 = NSolve[A1[p[P, α, β], q[Q, a], k[X[i]], k[X[i]] - p[P, α, β] - q[Q, a]] == f, Q, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
 If[solA1 != {},

  solA1 = Select[Q /. solA1, Positive];
  AppendTo[minA1, {{P, i, α, β, a}, Min[solA1] /. Infinity -> Null}];
  AppendTo[maxA1, {{P, i, α, β, a}, Max[solA1] /. -Infinity -> Null}];,

  AppendTo[minA1, {{P, i, α, β, a}, Null}];
  AppendTo[maxA1, {{P, i, α, β, a}, Null}]
  ],
 {P, 0, 5, dk}, {i, 0, 10, dk}, {α, 0, 3, dk}, {β, 0, 6, dk}, {a, 0, 3, dk},
 Method -> "CoarsestGrained"(*Automatic*)
]
```

I can't see anything I've done wrong, but I am fairly new to *Mathematica*, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54299/discussion-on-question-by-user35305-how-to-speed-up-code-in-paralleldo-loops).